# How to get email using the Robot Framework?

Tags: email, robotframework

I try to use the sample in the [robotframework-imaplibrary](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary/):

```python
Open Mailbox    host=imap.domain.com    user=${mail}    password=${PW}
${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=${sender}    timeout=300
${parts} =    Walk Multipart Email    ${LATEST}
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${parts}
\\    Walk Multipart Email    ${LATEST}
\\    ${content-type} =    Get Multipart Content Type
\\    Continue For Loop If    '${content-type}' != 'text/html'
\\    ${payload} =    Get Multipart Payload    decode=True
\\    Should Contain    ${payload}    your email
\\    ${HTML} =    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
\\    Should Contain    ${HTML}    Your email
Close Mailbox
```

I get the error for the 3rd line ( ${parts} =  Walk Multipart Email  ${LATEST} ) after the test run:

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Does anyone know a working example of an email checking?

Comment: which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about a mention for the line. The failed line is
Walk Multipart Email    ${LATEST}